# Dynamic ul / li 'table' structure in cshtml asp

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to create nice `ul li` structure for categories. One line of the structure would look like this

```
<li>
    <ul class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal'>
       <li></li><li></li><li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So as you can see no matter what in one line there are 3 elements. Normally it would be for inide for statement maybe:

```
   for(i=0;i=object.lenght%3;i++)
        for(i=0;i=3;i++)
```

so I first check How many lines I need than I distribute 3 li's maybe check if we have more li's than object lenght and do break but .... I don't know how to achieve this in cshtml .... I only managed to do as simple as one foreach statemant ;/

ok this works if anyone wants

```
  @for (float i = 0; i < (float)Model.Count() / 3; i++)
{
    var numObjects = @i * 3;               
        <li>
            <ul class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal'>
            @for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (numObjects == Model.Count())
                {
                    break;
                }
                <li>Element o numerze @numObjects </li>
                numObjects ++;                    
            }
            </ul>
        </li>
}
```

ONE LAST QUESTION :) in line where is :

```
  <li>Element o numerze @numObjects </li>
```

I want to select model elemeny of number j .... and i can't seem to find how to select - not by ID number becouse thy might not be incrementing by 1 or some record may have beend deleted  (if it works in foreach then there must be some way of getting it by number)

Comment: You will probably want to capitalize length and spell it correctly and declare `i` and use a different loop variable name for the inner loop and perform a comparison instead of an assignment in their conditions. And use `/ 3` instead of `%3`.

Comment: it  was just so show idea how i would do it but yeah your right the / would be proper operation for what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually when use second `for` you destroy the first `i`. You should change the variable like:

```
for(i=0;i=object.lenght%3;i++)
        for(j=0;j=3;j++)
```

And in CSHTML/Razor you can write like this:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < object.length/3; i++)
    @for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

Comment: how would that look in cshtml ? same as in c# (exepto for @at beggining)?

Comment: @user3311826 you have to use @